# Unit Testing Times Zones and a strategy to migrate to Multi-Locale TimeZones

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, datetime, timezone

<sub>While the question [How to unit test TimeZones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384038/how-to-unit-test-timezones) exists with a few answers it's more "How To" whereas this is a timezone conversion problem.</sub>

## Intro & Code Repo/Repro

I have a problem with the practical implementation of Unit Testing TimeZones. I made a Repo to quickly repro the problem converting an Australian date to two Time Zones in UTC -4 & -3: https://github.com/MeaningOfLights/UnitTestedTimeZones Brief Code:

```
[TestCaseSource("GetDataFromCSVTimeZonesAEST")]
public DateTime Should_Convert_From_AEST_To_OtherTimeZones(string timeZoneId, DateTime localAEST)
{
    // Act
    var foreignDateTime = TimeZoneHelper.DateFromAEST(localAEST, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId));

    //Assert
    return foreignDateTime;
}

private static IEnumerable GetDataFromCSVTimeZonesAEST()
{
    CsvReader reader = new CsvReader("TestData\\TimeZones.csv");
    bool firstLineHeader = true;
    while (reader.Next())
    {
        if (firstLineHeader)
        { 
            firstLineHeader = false;
            continue;
        }
        string regionTimeZoneId = reader[1].ToString();
        DateTime BaseAEST = DateTime.Parse(reader[2]);
        DateTime foreignDateTime = DateTime.Parse(reader[3]);
        yield return new TestCaseData(regionTimeZoneId, BaseAEST).Returns(foreignDateTime);
    }
}
```

## Background

I have a database with Australian dates that needs to support localized TimeZones. Since its a live system taking it offline to convert all the Australian AEST dates to UTC isn't easily possible and would need very good justification for the downtime.

I thought about using AEST as the base date metric instead of UTC. However, after a few tests considering Countries with/without Daylight Savings Time (DST) I'm already nervous about not using UTC as I suspect it will bite me - further.

## Testing

Testing this theory with AEST as a base date I see 2/20 tests failing. In the repo, in the Unit Test project is Test Data csv file:

[image]

When I run the Unit Tests, the two above highlighted tests fail, in fact any TimeZones I use for UTC -4 & -3 are failing.

```
+---------------------------------+-----------+
|     Time Zone                   | UTCOffset |
+---------------------------------+-----------+
| Paraguay Standard Time          | -04:00:00 |
| Atlantic Standard Time          | -04:00:00 |
| Venezuela Standard Time         | -04:00:00 |
| Central Brazilian Standard Time | -04:00:00 |
| SA Western Standard Time        | -04:00:00 |
| Pacific SA Standard Time        | -04:00:00 |
| Newfoundland Standard Time      | -03:30:00 |
| Tocantins Standard Time         | -03:00:00 |
| E. South America Standard Time  | -03:00:00 |
| SA Eastern Standard Time        | -03:00:00 |
| Argentina Standard Time         | -03:00:00 |
| Greenland Standard Time         | -03:00:00 |
| Montevideo Standard Time        | -03:00:00 |
| Magallanes Standard Time        | -03:00:00 |
| Saint Pierre Standard Time      | -03:00:00 |
| Bahia Standard Time             | -03:00:00 |
+---------------------------------+-----------+
```

Just to make things more confusing, Argentina is located at a longitude that would naturally put it in the UTC−04:00 or UTC−05:00 time zone; however, [it actually uses the UTC−03:00 time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Argentina#:%7E:text=Argentina%20is%20located%20at%20a,%E2%88%9203%3A00%20time%20zone.). Although I'm expecting UTC -4:00 from the .Net Core TimeZoneInfo.

[image]

## Debugging steps

[Clone the project](https://github.com/MeaningOfLights/UnitTestedTimeZones), open the UnitTest.cs class file and press Ctrl + R + T or click Run Tests.

## Results

I can't work out why these two fail, I'm not sure about Daylight Saving (DST) as other TimeZones without it work fine. Can someone please give me a hand to understand what's going on?

Also, am I correct with my concerns about using AEST instead of UTC as the DataBase DateTime format?

<sub>Coding on Windows 10, this UnitTest project is to test it all works on Linux Distro's. Many thanks!</sub>

## Update

I updated the TimeZones.csv with details. The problem is Brazil sits across multiple Time Zones and Argentina uses Brazils UTC -3. By recording all the DateTimes in UTC on the server (after converting AEST dates to UTC) we'll simply let the users decide the TimeZone:

[image]

Comment: I quickly compared the local times of Buenos Aires and AEST, [see here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20220630T162600&p1=tz_aest&p2=51) and they differ from your expected result. So your code seems to be correct, but `TimeZones.csv` is wrong at least for Buenos Aires

Comment: Thanks I changed the two rows to use IANA TimeZoneId, eg America/Argentina/Bruenos_Aires and that fixes it. I think I'll test it all on Linux the target. Since Brazil stopped using DST in 2019 I figure I've you're right I've got an old spreadsheet.

Comment: You're welcome :) just give it a try and if it is okay for you, I'll convert my comment into an answer so that you can close the question

Comment: IMHO don't use `DateTime`. Though it's fine for UTC and maybe abstract (unknown) timezones. The various api's barely work for anything else. Use `DateTimeOffset` instead, it's *much* easier to work with multiple timezones.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I'm using [`DateTimeInfo`](https://github.com/vivet/Vivet.AspNetCore/tree/master/Vivet.AspNetCore.RequestTimeZone#vivetaspnetcorerequesttimezone)

Comment: Yeah, I built something similar; setting a timezone cookie in javascript, middleware to set an `AsyncLocal`. But I mean that you shouldn't attempt to create a `DateTime` in any timezone. If your database stores AEST, I would write a value converter to turn that into a `DateTimeOffset` to fix the core problem. Then the rest of your code can be *much* simpler.